# What sort of connector is this?

Tags: identification, connector

Can anyone tell me what kind of connector is shown on the far right of this image? I have a broken connection and would like to replace the connector.

[image: Connector on the far right]

Comment: Give us more information. Some measurements, a view of both halves when disconnected, that sort of thing.

Comment: 2.54 mm JST perhaps?

Comment: Supposedly they are JST XH series but the right angle through-hole header (S2B-XH-A-1(LF)(SN)) has little fins extending out around the leads.  Could be a clone, the plug looks identical.  I'd say buy one for $0.18 and see if it works but they are out of stock.

Comment: You'll need more than the connector.  There's crimped terminals on the wire ends.  You don't have the crimps, and you don't have the proper crimping tool.  You should seek an entire connector assembly and splice the wires.   Previous posters are right, those are "JST"  (JST is a company name)   Those connectors are "standard" in RC toys for battery connections.  You can get entire wire assemblies right off Ebay.   Just search "JST connectors" - I found hundreds of assemblies with that search phrase.   Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me what kind of connector

Literally what *Kind*? The *kind* is a rectangular wire-to-board connector, single-row, unlatched.

If you also want to know specifically what that connector is:

1. Measure the exact [pitch](https://www.google.com/search?q=connector+pitch) in mm (e.g., 2.5 mm)
2. Go to my [Indenticonn](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=discrete_1row_w2b_conn)
3. Select the menu item in the left of  for that pitch (e.g., "1 row 2.5 mm discrete W2B connectors")
4. Then hover on the "components" list and look at the images on the right column
5. Compare them to the looks of your connector

Hopefully, yours is listed in there.